# Can't get selected value of UIPickerView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Here is my code

class.h

```
.......
{
  NSInteger selectedRow;
}
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger selectedRow;
.......
```

classs.m

```
 @synthesize selectedRow = _selectedRow;
    .......
UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 150, 280, 100)];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
[self.view addSubview:picker];

self.selectedRow =  [picker selectedRowInComponent:0];
```

When a button is pressed selector dog is called

```
-(void)dbg
{
  NSLog(@"%d", self.selectedRow) -- RESULT 0
  NSLOg(@"%@", self.selectedRow) -- RESULT null
}
```

What I miss here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSLog(@"%@", …)`prints objects, but NSInteger is a primitive type. The first NSLog should work correctly.

You have to implement the picker's delegate, especially `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:`

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    self.selectedRow = row;
}
```

Comment: Nope. %d gives value of 0 every time.

Answer (score 0):

%d means integer

%@ means object

you can read this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html